# How to use the 4Pin Power Connector on the DL360 Gen9 Server?

Tags: server

I have a DL360 Gen9 server and I have 6 SSDs in the slots (slots 1-6) on controller 1 (P840 array controller). This is at PCI Slot1. These should serve as storage. I put 2 more SSDs in the slot where the bezel is so I can connect the hard drives to the other controller. This is a P840 array controller. According to the instructions, these 2 additional SSDs are connected to the 4-pin connector on the board, to which the other hard drives are connected. (see instructions at https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/c04471520 page 62) So I have occupied a total of 8 out of 10 possible slots. As soon as I connect the 2 SSDs to the four pins on the backplane, the server does not start and gives the following message in the error log: Server Critical Fault (Service Information: Power On Fault, System Board, AUX/Main EFUSE Regulator 1 (10h)) I cant understand this fault. Because I only use 8 of the 8 planned hard drives and even if I use more hard drives, the 4pin still has to work. I use as many hard drives as there are maximum connections on the backplane. A problem with the energy supply therefore makes no sense. The hard drives work in slots 7 and 8, but then they are attached to the wrong controller. What can I do to fix the problem?

Thank you for your ideas.

Luca

I unplugged the 4 pin connector. The server starts as requested. If I reconnect the disks and do a full cold boot it still doesn't work.
My goal is that the 4pin on the backplane supplies my additional hard drives with power, as the instructions say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again as an update:
In my opinion, HPE intentionally blocks this connection in the "small" models that have "too little" power supply power.
I have now supplied the SSDs with power via a USB to Sata adapter and oh surprise, no problem with the power supply.